# These PDF library is commercial use?

Tags: android, pdf, pdflib, pdf-viewer

I read this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android .

Vikas Patidar mentions that there are some open source library on Android like

- Android PDF Viewer
- APDFViewer
- droidreader
- android-pdf

Some of them are licensed with GNU GPL v2. Some of them are licensed with GNU GPL v3.
I want to ask whether they can be used in a commercial applcation.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197503/to-gpl-or-to-not-gpl-that-is-the-question You question is about GPL really not specifically PDF libraries

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, i don't know how to ask.

Comment: @jiduvah : Can you answer me? And then, i can tick your answer for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking into GPL licences rather than PDF libraries, then you will have a better idea of what you will have to do to include it in your project. Here are some resources.

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197503/to-gpl-or-to-not-gpl-that-is-the-question

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know if you can use a GPL library in a commercial, closed-source application without paying a single cent, then the answer is no, you cannot.